# Intuition - Identities with 2-Cycles and 3-Cycles - Mulholland p. 69, 86 - Fraleigh p. 90

Tags: group-theory, permutations, intuition

[Jamie Mulholland](http://www.sfu.ca/~jtmulhol/math302/notes/302notes.pdf) p. 69 Theorem 6.1 or  Fraleigh p. 90 Corollary 9.12
 Any permutation of a finite set of at least two elements is a product of 2-cycles.

> $1. (a_1, a_2, ···,a_n)= (a_1, a_n)(a_1, a_{n-1}) · · · (a_1, a_3)(a_1, a_2).
> \implies 5. (a, b)(a, c) = (a, b, c)  $

Jamie Mulholland p. 75 for 2 to 4 and p. 86 for 5, 6. I skip $(c,d)(a,b) = (a,b)(c,d)$.

> $2.$ $(a, b)(a, b) = id   \qquad  3. (a,c)(a, b) = (a, b)(b, c) \qquad 4. (b, c)(a, b) = (a, c)(c, b)$
>
> $6. (a, b)(c, d) = (a, b, c)(a, d, c)$

[I tried](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499613/logic-for-decomposing-permutation-into-transpositions). I know how to check LHS = RHS by following each element but I don't want to do this every time. What's the intuition for the 6 identites?

Comment: Reading from right to left, every time $\;a_i\;,\;\;i\ge 2\;$ appears, it **won't** appear again further to the left. This gives you an easy, nice way to realize the RHS product.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Can you answer with more detail?

Comment: For the RHSs of $3$ and $4$, you are simply taking the permutation form and writing it down. You know that $a\mapsto b$ and $b\mapsto c$ so your cycle must also have this. So it must have the form $(a,b)(b,c)$.

Comment: (As an aside, I don't like this question. I would argue that, really, there is no (useful) intuition for these six identities, and so this question is pretty close to unanswerable.)

Answer (score 1):

> $1. (a_1, a_2, ···,a_n)= (a_1, a_n)(a_1, a_{n-1}) · · · (a_1, a_3)(a_1, a_2).$

You can visualize the LHS as moving every letter to its destination all at once, while the RHS moves each letter one at a time, keeping $a_1$ as a "working" slot until the end.

For example, let's look at $\sigma \triangleq (1,2,3,\cdots, n)$.  You can envision picking all the numbers up together, shifting them over by one slot, and then sitting them back down again.  That's the LHS.  On the RHS, you just swap two at a time.  Each time, you take whatever is in the $a_1$ spot to the spot that $\sigma$ is supposed to put it, and bring whichever letter is in that spot back with you to the $a_1$ spot.  When you finally get to $a_n$ after moving all the other letters, every letter will have been moved to its proper place, including $a_n$, which belongs in the $a_1$ spot.

> $2.$ $(a, b)(a, b) = \text{id}$

If a coin faces heads up and you turn it over twice, you'll end up back where you started, right?  In this example, heads is $a$, and tails is $b$.

> $3.$ $(a,c)(a, b) = (a, b)(b, c)$

Using #2, we can multiply on the left by $(a,b)$ to get $(a,b)(a,c)(a, b) = (b, c)$.  By #1, the LHS is $(b,c,b)=(b,c)$.

> $4.$ $(b, c)(a, b) = (a, c)(c, b)$

This is the same thing as #3.  Since $(b,c)=(c,b)$ and $(a,c)=(c,a)$, we can multiply on the left by $(c,b)$ to get $(a, b) = (c,b)(c,a)(c, b)=(b,a,b)=(a,b)$.

> $5.$ $(a, b)(a, c) = (a, b, c)$

This is a special case of #1.

> $6.$ $(a, b)(c, d) = (a, b, c)(a, d, c)$

My best advice for this one is to just work it out on a table with some cups, cards, or coins.  Pretend you're a card dealer- permute! Get a feel for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upvoted. (1.) I'm confounded by the long sentences starting with 'On the RHS..."?  Are there pictures? Latex drains a lot of time hence I'm not looking for something with Latex. (2.) I understand your coin analogy, but how does $(a,b)(a,b)$ flesh out turning over heads twice?

Comment: Can you please notify me in your answer, and not in comments?

Comment: @FrankMuer There aren't pictures, sorry.  Formulae must be written in MathJax on this site.  About the coin analogy, you are switching the position of heads and tails twice; this is the same thing as switching the position of $a$ and $b$ twice.  For the explanation of #1, I strongly suggest you **work out an example** while you read through my answer more closely.  I suggest laying out 6 or 7 playing cards on a desk and permuting those according to the left hand side, and then doing so again according to the right hand side.